# Can a C# .exe file be accessed by multiple users simultaneously?

Tags: c#

I created a small program for one department in our company. I put the C# exe file in one of the shared hard drives on our network. Will there be problems when the exe file accessed by multiple users at the same time?

Comment: Do you store program data inside some files in the same directory ? Do you have config files ? If your app is just the exe file itself with some other dlls, then no you would have no problem. Although it is better that the users copy that program to their machines and use a local copy.

Comment: Windows will cope with launching multiple instances; that's not a direct issue. You, however, will need to be able to handle anything that needs to be user-specific (settings, permissions, etc.). And then you need to make sure users can't delete the application from the share :)

Comment: If they, like you, have privileges to the network share, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

On the general, yes it can.

On the specific, and as mentioned in the comments by others, what then remains to be asked is

- what the application does.
- if there is any user-specific functionality or dependency.
- if the application can handle concurrency for reads and writes/updates on a DB or file-level(depending on its data sources)